# Option seleted value created dinamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

I want to create dinamically this select from [Framework7](https://v4.framework7.io/docs/smart-select.html):

```
 <a href="#" class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init">
    <!-- select -->
    <select name="fruits">
      <option value="apple" selected>Apple</option> 
      <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
      ...
```

So in my code I get values from a database and I create the elements. I am specially focused on the `seleted` attribute :

```
_db_getvalues.company(id, function (result) {
            if (result.rows.length > 0) {

                var element = document.getElementById(mySmartselect);
               
               
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.setAttribute('selected', result.rows.item(i).name);
                    option.value = result.rows.item(i).name;
                    option.text = result.rows.item(i).name;
                    option.setAttribute('data-identificador', result.rows.item(i).name);
                    element.add(option);
                
            }
           
        });
```

But does not work;

> option.setAttribute('selected', result.rows.item(i).name);

does not have effect over my option list

This is the HTML part

```
<a class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init" data-open-in="popover">
   <select name="" id="mysmartselect">
                                      
   </select>
   <div class="item-content" >
   <div class="item-inner" >
    div class="item-title">Group</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
```

this is what I want to see:

[image]

but this is what I get

[image]

What I am doing wrong? I am not facing error on the console.

Comment: Sometimes you write "result" and sometimes "resultado". Is that correct?

Comment: The selected attribute doesn't have a value.  It's mear existance on an option is what makes the option selected. [HTML Standard boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute)

Comment: `if (result.rows.length > ) {` <= this is also a typo I assume?

Comment: @thingEvery I have fix it,  sorry

Comment: Make sure the update the question if your logic changes or is inaccurate.

Comment: Can you output `result` to the console and include it in your question? Also, please fix the typo that @Taplar pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has some **syntax problem**.

1- one of the `div` tag doesn't have closed `</div>`

2-var `element = document.getElementById("mySmartselect"); // class names have to between "`

anyway if we assume you returned data is working correctly then your code after syntax fix would work:

```js
     var element = document.getElementById("mySmartselect");

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.setAttribute('selected', 'apple'+i);
                    option.value = 'apple'+i
                    option.text = 'apple'+i;
                    option.setAttribute('data-identificador', 'apple'+i);
                    element.add(option);
                }
```

```html
<a class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init" data-open-in="popover">
   <select name="" id="mySmartselect">
   </select>
   <div class="item-content" >
   <div class="item-inner" >
    <div class="item-title">Group</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
```